# C++ template function that takes as template iterator and returns a vector with the type of the iterator

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to create a function that takes two iterators of template type. The function shall return all the odd values of values contained in the interval of the iterators. I've tried to create a second typename T2 and use it the place of the "??" in the code snippet.

```
      template <typename T1>
      std::vector<??> odd(T1 start,T1 end){
          std::vector<??> result;
          while(start++!=end){
            if(*result % 2 == 1){
              ans.push_back(*start);
            }
          }
          return result;
        }
        int main(){
            int a[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
            udda(std::begin(a),std::end(a));
        }
```

What i want the function to do is to create a vector of the same class as the iterators and return it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [decltype](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) and [trailing return types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function):

```
template <typename T1> 
auto odd(T1 start, T1 end) 
    -> std::vector<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*start)>::type>
{ 
    /* ... */ 
}
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/pkZtpXrS5wXEdH5v)

Comment: I get a compile error when i try to use decltype and dereferencing a iterator?

Comment: @JakobSvenningsson: sorry about that, you need a remove_reference_t as well.

Comment: Fixed the answer and added a wandbox example.